# SQL Add Numbers To Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select, sql-server-2012

I have a basic SELECT DISTINCT statement that is returning a list of course prefixes (ENG, MAT, SCI, etc...). I'd like the select to also return a set group of numbers (100-500) after the prefix. So the end data set will look like what's below:

```
ENG 100
ENG 200
ENG 300
ENG 400
ENG 500
MAT 100
MAT 200
MAT 300
MAT 400
MAT 500
SCI 100
SCI 200
SCI 300
SCI 400
SCI 500
```

Here is my original script to pull the course prefixes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    LEFT(SECTIONS.EVENT_ID, charindex(' ', SECTIONS.EVENT_ID) - 1) as EVENT_ID
FROM SECTIONS
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you use: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: @GMB Done. Thanks for the reminder GMB.

Comment: Just cross join against a list. Either save the list in a table or create it with `union all` or `values`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `cross join` your current results with the list of numbers to generate all possible combinations:

```
select s.event_id, v.num
from (
    select distinct left(sections.event_id, charindex(' ', sections.event_id) - 1) as event_id
    from sections
) s
cross join (values (100), (200), (300), (400), (500)) v(num)
```

Or if you want to concatenate the `event_id` and the numbers in a single column:

```
select concat(s.event_id, ' ', v.num) new_event_id
from (
    select distinct left(sections.event_id, charindex(' ', sections.event_id) - 1) as event_id
    from sections
) s
cross join (values (100), (200), (300), (400), (500)) v(num)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much @GMB!